# Make the cursor invisible when a user hovers over a div

Tags: html, css

I want to make the cursor pointer invisible when user hovers over a specific div.

```
<div class="holder" style="width:200;height:200">
    <div class="mouse-invisible"  style="width:50;height:50">
          Dare to Hover Me !!!
    </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't. Just don't.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Quite right, although you should say *why*. Have added an alternative to my answer below based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

A simple cursor style will do, but as the cursor is only visible on "hover" you do not need to add `:hover` to the style. Just use:

```
.mouse-invisible{
    cursor:none;
}
```

As @T.J. Crowder *hints at*, hiding the cursor from the user, at all, is a bad user experience. Better to substitute a finer cursor (like `crosshair`) so that the object is less obscured:

e.g.

```
.mouse-invisible{
    cursor:crosshair;
}
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Answer (score 0):

You must use the CSS property `cursor` and set it to `none`.

```css
.mouse-invisible {
  cursor: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mouse-invisible">
  Dare to Hover Me !!!
</div>
```

Comment: `:hover` not needed like @TrueBlueAussie said. I edited.

Comment: @jbutler483 True ! Originaly it was to preserve the OP's coding style but it's better with a proper CSS of course. I edited.

Comment: @jbutler483 Thanks, it's way more sexy (and more understandable) like that.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```
.mouse-invisible{
    cursor: none;
}
```

[**Know more about CSS cursor Property**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/w0756Lho/1/)

Comment: `hover` is redundant... when else is the cursor visible? :)

Comment: I meant: `cursor` is one style that *never* needs `hover` as it only occurs *with the mouse over the element!* :)